# Is it possible to reduce fields in front page view in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

THi is the image of what kibana shows in json format

[image]

As you can see in the lsit view it shows all the fields like message , timestamp bla etc.

I want that in list view i can only see `message` nothing else and on left i cansee all feilds so that i can filter if i want to.

Is it possible

Comment: In your ES query, you can define the `"_source"` key, which takes a string array contains the required fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, by using this functionality: [Adding Field Columns to the Documents Table](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html#adding-columns)

[image]